# Find string in array and remove

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find a string in an array `sql` and remove the string.  The string would be like:

```
   "  specimen.snop_code = ''"
```

There will be 4 digits between the single qoutes, which could be anything.  I was thinking of using regex to find the string.

Tried just using pop() but I need to target the string to be removed from the array.  Note that I need to remove all instances of the string. So something like:

```
disease_filter =  new RegExp(" specimen.snop_code = ''", 'g');
    for (var i=sql.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (sql[i] === disease_filter) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
    }
```

So how can I make  `" specimen.snop_code = '*'"` into a regular expression with a wildcard as shown between the single quotes?

Comment: Give some examples of what will be the source string and what will be the expected output string

Comment: I don't think you can use a regexp with `splice()`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to replace the 4 digits with?

Comment: Sorry should have explained that I was looking at using regex to find string in array.  See updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace` with a regex as the first parameter:

```
var input = " specimen.snop_code = 'something'";
var disease_filter = input.replace(/'(.*)'/gi, "'other stuff'");
// disease_filter is now "specimen.snop_code = 'other stuff'"
```

edit: removed unneccesary escaping as commented.

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes in the regexp.